# fetch parameters passed with url into nginx.conf by lua in Openresty

Tags: nginx, lua

I am having a url '/gifts/' below is code of nginx.conf file which is managing logic.

```
location /gifts {
    default_type text/html;
    set $target '';
    content_by_lua '
        local redis = require "resty.redis"; 
        local red = redis:new()
        red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec
        local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
        if not ok then
            ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err, "Redis failed to connect")
            return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
        end
        local ok1, err = red:set("Animal", "DOG")
        if not ok then
            ngx.say("Failed to set cache in redis", err)
        end 
        local res, err = red:get("Animal")
        if not res then
            ngx.say("Failure", err)
        end
        ngx.say("Animal", res)
';
}
```

It is working fine for me with `/gifts/`
But i have one requirement like i want to fetch parameters into this login like
`/gifts?key=name&value=Prashant`
I want to fetch value of  key and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used req.get_uri_args()  to get all parameters passed in url.

```
local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.. it gives 500 internal server error. Can you share how you did it in more detail please?

Comment: Please tell me with which context you are using this .?  you can use this only with set_by_lua, rewrite_by_lua, access_by_lua, content_by_lua, header_filter_by_lua, body_filter_by_lua, log_by_lua

Comment: I resolved it by using `ngx.var.uri()` instead. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`ngx.req.get_uri_args()`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_uri_args), this  will return a Lua table holding all the current request URL query arguments.

Example:

```
 location = /test {
    content_by_lua '
        local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
        for key, val in pairs(args) do
            if type(val) == "table" then
                ngx.say(key, ": ", table.concat(val, ", "))
            else
                ngx.say(key, ": ", val)
            end
        end
    ';
}
```